# Network Error from React Native axios call to Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, axios

I am trying to make an Axios call from my React Native app, but I get the following error:[image: error message]

Here is a snippet of the code I'm using. This is based off an axios tutorial I tried which worked, but instead of getting 'response.data' I am just trying to get 'response.message' to see if it's actually connecting.[image: React Native code]

FYI I created my API using Node.js and Express.

Comment: Yeah, the link is accessible. As for the response, I was going based off of this example (https://aboutreact.com/react-native-axios/). They used `response.data`; but I tried yours just incase and it gave me the same error. Not sure if it has anything to do with the 'http' vs 'https'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have are runing both applications on development and if that is true you will have little issue accessing your local API runing on your computer from your phone.

**Solution 1**

1. Connect your phone and laptop to the same wifi network or hotspot
2. Get the ip address of your computer e.g **195.938.84.4** you can browse how to get ip address on your machine
3. put the ip address you got into your API call URL on your code, your code becomes http://195.938.84.4:8000

Because your phone and computer are connected on the same network it means they can find each other on that network using each others ip addresses.

**Solution 2**

You can try using **chrome port forwarding**

1. make sure your phone is connected to your computer using a usb cable and make sure you run the command **adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081** and it runs successfully
2. open up a chrome browser on the url input and type **chrome://inspect**
3. click on the port ***forwarding option*** and on the **port** input field and  enter **8000** which is the port your API is runing on your PC and on the **port and address** input field enter **localhost:8000** then click done.
4. click on **configure** and on **ip address and port** input field enter **localhost:8000** and press done
5. change your url on code to **http://localhost:8000**
6. To test your api before using your phone just write a dummy route on your express server create a **GET request** route **/test** and respond with a json response and open up your chrome browser and send request to http://localhost:8000/test. if it works then it means your react-native app can now access your local API,  refresh over again if it doesnt work or review steps.

Comment: I've been stuck on this for too long and the first solution helped out! Still need to do modifications but now I can confirm that its connecting and getting the data.